# How to get my 404 page to show after upgrade of Sails.js to 0.10.x?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-status-code-404, sails.js

I've upgraded my `Sails.js` app to `0.10.x` and now when I point my browser at a non-existent route such as `http://localhost:1337/notfound` instead of my `views/404.jade` being served up I just get a bit of JSON

```
{
  "status": 404
}
```

I built a default new sails app `sails new dummy --template=jade` just to compare and contrast with what I have in my existing app, and the only obvious difference I see is that in `dummy/config/` there is a file called `http.js`

I've copied that file over to my app but it's made no difference.

I've also ensured that the tasks in `dummy/tasks` are identical to my own app's tasks.

In `dummy/config/routes.js` it says

> - Finally, if those don't match either, the default 404 handler is triggered.
> - See `config/404.js` to adjust your app's 404 logic.

Which is obviously out of date as `0.10.x` apps use the `api/responses` mechanisms.

So I am at rather a loss as to how to get this to work.

I am using `0.10.0-rc8` (and I have confirmed that this is the same in my dummy app as well as my actual app)

Answer (score 0):

Well I've fixed this but I have no idea why it was happening.

To fix it I created a new project as per the method described in my question, but with the same name as my existing project, then, file-by-file, I painstakingly moved across everything specific to my app, taking care to leave in place anything new generated by sails.

Once I'd done that I ran my tests - all passed - and then `sails lift` and tried it, and yay, everything worked and I got my `404` error page back.

I committed my changes and then carefully picked through a comparison of what had changed.

Alas nothing at all stands out, so, while I have solved my problem, I have no idea what the original cause was.

Answer (score 0):

From the section in the [migration guide](http://beta.sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/Upgrading) on "Custom Responses":

> In v0.10, you can now generate your own custom server responses. [See
>   here to learn how](http://beta.sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/Custom-Responses). Like before, there are a few that we automatically
>   create for you. Instead of generating myApp/config/500.js and other
>   .js responses in the config directory, they are now generated in
>   myApp/api/responses/. To migrate, you will need to create a new v0.10
>   project and copy the myApp/api/responses directory into your existing
>   app. You will then modify the appropriate .js file to reflect any
>   customization you made in your response logic files (500.js,etc).

Basically, v0.10.x gives you more freedom in how things like `res.notFound`, `res.serverError` and even `res.ok()` (success response) work, but you need to copy over the new `api/responses` folder to migrate.

Comment: Yeah I did that but it just wasn't working. I was just getting a json 404 message, not the html 404

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but was using 0.9.x. Probably a better solution but I outputted a view instead of JSON in all cases.

Update config/404.js to replace res.json() with res.view():

```
if (err) { 
  //return res.json(result, result.status); } 
  return res.view('404')  // <-- output the 404 view instead
}
```

Then, just make sure in your routes.js file it will redirect the /404. Place the following at the bottom of your routes.js file:

```
'/*': {
  view: '*'
},
```